# c++ opengl cant move object with glBufferSubData

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I try to move my object only on the y-axis. I created an array with 4 Vertex and put the data in my vertexBuffer and bind it. Also I created a vertexArray and an indexBuffer to bind them and draw my quad.

Now I change only the y-coordinate of my quad and want to overwrite the data in my vertexBuffer with `glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(moveObject), moveObject);` but nothing happens. Only when I fill the data before I bind my indexbuffer it will work. After that I can't change the VertexBuffer.

Here is my code of my main

```
#include <iostream>
#include "headerData/VertexBuffer.h"
#include "headerData/IndexBuffer.h"
#include "headerData/Shader.h"
#include "headerData/VertexLayout.h"
#include "headerData/VertexArray.h"
#include "headerData/Road.h"
#include "glm.hpp"
#include <gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <gtc/type_ptr.hpp>


static struct VertexShader {
    std::string defaultShader = "#version 330 core\n"
        "layout (location = 0) in vec4 aPos;\n"
        "uniform mat4 scale;"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "gl_Position =  vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0f)*scale;\n"
        "}\0";

    std::string yMoveShader = "#version 330 core\n"
        "layout (location = 0) in vec4 aPos;\n"
        "uniform mat4 scale;"
        "uniform vec4 transform;\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "gl_Position =  vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y+transform.y, aPos.z, 1.0f)*scale;\n"
        "}\0";
};

static struct FragmentShader {

    std::string defaultShader = "#version 330 core\n"
        "out vec4 FragColor;\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "   FragColor = vec4(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0);\n"
        "}\n\0";

    std::string greenShader = "#version 330 core\n"
        "out vec4 FragColor;\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "   FragColor = vec4(0.5f, 1.0f, 0.5f, 1.0);\n"
        "}\n\0";

};

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
void processInput(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
}

int main()
{
    // glfw: initialize and configure
    // ------------------------------
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);


#ifdef __APPLE__
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
#endif

    // glfw window creation
    // --------------------
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 800, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);

    // glad: load all OpenGL function pointers
    // ---------------------------------------
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // set up vertex data (and buffer(s)) and configure vertex attributes
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------

    VertexShader vertexShader;
    FragmentShader fragmentShader;
    Shader shaderCol(vertexShader.defaultShader, fragmentShader.defaultShader);
    Shader shaderMove(vertexShader.yMoveShader, fragmentShader.greenShader);
    shaderCol.bind();
    //shaderMove.bind();
    glm::mat4 scale = glm::ortho(-100.0f, 100.0f, -100.0f, 100.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    //glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderMove.getShaderID(), "scale"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(scale));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderCol.getShaderID(), "scale"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(scale));
    glm::vec3 transform(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);


    float moveObject[] = {
         20.0f,  -50.0f,  // top right
         20.0f, -90.0f,  // bottom right
        -20.0f, -90.0f,  // bottom left
        -20.0f,  -50.0f   // top left


    };

    float colObject[] = {
        2.0f, 2.0f,         //top right
        2.0f, -2.0f,        //bottom right
        -2.0f, 2.0f,        //top left
        -2.0, -2.0f         //bot left
    };

    unsigned int indices[] = {  // note that we start from 0!
        0, 1, 3,   // first triangle
        1, 2, 3    // second triangle
    };

    unsigned int VA, VB, IB;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VA);


    // bind the Vertex Array Object first, then bind and set vertex buffer(s), and then configure vertex attributes(s).

    //glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    //glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    //VertexBuffer vb;
    //vb.bind(moveObject, 4 * 2 * sizeof(float));

    //VertexBuffer
    glGenBuffers(1, &VB);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VB);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 8 * 2 * sizeof(float), nullptr, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glBindVertexArray(VA);


    //LAyout vom Buffer
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(float), (void*)(0));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);


    //VertexLayout layout;
    //layout.layoutPush(3);
    //VertexArray va;
    //va.addBuffer(vb, layout);
    //IndexBuffer ib;
    //ib.bind(indices, 6 * sizeof(unsigned int));

    glGenBuffers(1, &IB);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IB);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(unsigned int), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, IB);


    //Parameter
    //glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)(0));
    //glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    //glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    //glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);


    // uncomment this call to draw in wireframe polygons.
    //glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
    //Road road;

    // render loop
    // -----------
    float time = 0;
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // input
        // -----
        processInput(window);

        // render
        // ------
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        //shader.bind();
        //glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*)(sizeof(unsigned int) * 3));
        //glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        //glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*)(sizeof(unsigned int) * 3));
        //glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        //road.render();

        
        //That not work
        moveObject[1] += abs(90 * sin(glfwGetTime()));
        moveObject[3] += abs(90 * sin(glfwGetTime()));
        moveObject[5] += abs(90 * sin(glfwGetTime()));
        moveObject[7] += abs(90 * sin(glfwGetTime()));
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(moveObject), moveObject);
        


        //transform.y = 90 * abs(sin(glfwGetTime()));
        //glUniform4f(glGetUniformLocation(shaderMove.getShaderID(), "transform"), transform.x, transform.y, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        //glDeleteBuffers(1, &IB);

        //glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        // glBindVertexArray(0); // no need to unbind it every time 

        // glfw: swap buffers and poll IO events (keys pressed/released, mouse moved etc.)
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    // optional: de-allocate all resources once they've outlived their purpose:
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &test);


    // glfw: terminate, clearing all previously allocated GLFW resources.
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}


void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    std::cout << "callback" << std::endl;
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to just make a uniform variable in the shader to change all the coordinates in the shader? Won't need to hassle with buffers update

Comment: I think I have more ways to move an object. One way is with the shader but with an shader u can't detect collisions. Moreover you have to program around when u want to move with shader and detect a colission. Therefore I search for an other way where I can change my quad and use the coordinations of my quad to detect the collision.

Comment: It's a big waste to resend a million of vertices just to move an object. If your object has a bounding box (or some simplified mesh), and you know the translation/transform (and you do, because you pass it in the shader). Then you can replicate the transform on the bounding box on CPU side, without need to resend all the vertices. Transfering data is a huuuuge bottleneck. GPUs are good to send data once and reuse it for many draws

Comment: Okay I thought is a matter of how big my data ist. I mean I know that my box begins without an offset and ends by 4*2*sizeof(float) so I can overwrite only this section of my Vertex Array. And in the end the performance would be better than write a complex transformation in my shader.

When I only use shader, when I use the state GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW

Comment: A typical transformation comes down to a simple matrix/vector multiplication though. The penalty of data transfer scales with data size, yes. But it also has an overhead of just synchronizing two devices to send and receive the data. Even if you send like 10 numbers, the stall you get is quite huge

Comment: Okay so I can notice that in practice only shaders are used to change objects. So I have to make a copy of my object and perform the same calculations that are executed in the shader to find out at the end if a collision has taken or not

Comment: You typically don't compute collisions on the objects themselves, but on some simplified bounding boxes/spheres, and those are stored not as vertices, but as parameters (say only center and radius for a sphere). To find a collision of two spherical colliders you just transform two centers, and check that distance between the centers is smaller than sum of two radiuses. A more sophisticated collision system requires more thinking, of course

Comment: Order of matrix multiplications matters. If you want to apply projection matrix - `scale` to input vertices, it should be `scale * position` in shader's code.

Comment: Jea on this time I just wanted to watch what happen when I do ```position*scale```. Just for my own interest. 

Anyway @Alexey Larionov thank you for these informations :) I will do it with shaders than.

Answer (score 2):

When you execute this line

```
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(moveObject), moveObject);
```

the data bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` on GPU is updated. But what data is it bound to? Look above

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, IB);
```

You seem to bind your **array of indices**, while you probably meant

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VB);
```

Comment: Okay I watched in my tutorials and u are right. I don't have to bind my indexBuffer so I delet ```glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, IB);```. But still when I move ```glBufferSubData(...) into my while loop it still not working.

Comment: Not only you need to delete the line, but also bind `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` to `VB`, because this is the vertex buffer you want to change

Comment: Sorry I am a little bit dumb or missunderstand it. On the section where I comment ```//VertexBuffer``` I bind it once and than I set the Buffer with ```nullptr```. When I fill my buffer with ```glBufferSubData``` do I have to bind it again ?

Comment: Yeah, you're correct that it already should be bound to `VB`, but now I wonder what's the error...